# With iptables, match packets arrived via IPSEC tunnel

Tags: linux, iptables, ipsec

I'm using IPSEC in a tunnel mode.

How to make an iptables rule that will match only packets which arrived via IPSEC tunnel (i.e. **after** IPSEC decrypted them - **not** the IPSEC packets when they arrive and before decryption).

The point is to have a certain port which will be accessible only via IPSEC and inaccessible to the rest of the world.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use the policy module, and specify the `ipsec` policy, to match this traffic.  The following rule, for example, allows all inbound traffic to tcp port 12345.  Don't forget that rule order is important in `iptables`, and that you may need to allow the return-half packets as well, depending on your current `OUTPUT` restrictions.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m policy --pol ipsec --dir in -p tcp --dport 12345 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Finally I tested it, and indeed it works for me. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got your problem fixed!